# Cloud9 Password On Beaglebone Black

Tags: cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack

I'm using the Debian image for the BBB from here: Debian (BeagleBone Black - 2GB eMMC) 2014-05-14

This image has the Cloud9 IDE built-in. It works quite nicely for my purposes, but I can't figure out how to add a password. Anyone on the network can go to 11.22.33.44:3000 (not the actual IP address) and the IDE will automatically log them in as "John Doe" (No password requested).

Is there a way to request a user name and password when logging into Cloud9? I'm ok if the browser saves the password, but it should ask at least once

Comment: Does your BeagleBone Black have internet access?

Comment: Yes, I am running a successful programme right now even. My concern is any one on the LAN can access the code via port 3000 if they know the IP of BBB. Any idea?

Comment: I've tried messing with the `/opt/cloud9/build/standalonebuild/settings/standalone.js` file. In it, within the `user` keyword, I tried adding a `password` keyword and `pass` keyword, then I assign a value to these two plus the `pubkey` keyword. I also changed the value of `fullname`. After reboot, the username is changed (not John Doe anymore), but it still does not prompt for password. I believe that this file is probably where you set the password though. If not, I can only think of ip address authentication, which I have no idea how to implement.

Comment: I have posted the solution. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: WOW !!! That worked like a charm. Just Tested and no words to say how happy I am as I was trying so many things from a week now. Thanks again !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the solution.

To set a default username and password:

1. Open the file `/opt/cloud9/build/standalonebuild/configs/standalone.js`.
2. Locate the following code block. (Should be at the top of the file)

```
    if (!optimist.local) {
        optimist
            .boolean("t")
            .describe("t", "Start in test mode")
            .describe("k", "Kill tmux server in test mode")
            .default("b", false)
            .describe("b", "Start the bridge server - to receive commands from the cli")
            .default("w", config.workspaceDir)
            .describe("w", "Workspace directory")
            .alias("p", "port")
            .default("port", process.env.PORT || config.port)
            .describe("port", "Port")
            .alias("d", "debug")
            .default("debug", false)
            .describe("debug", "Turn debugging on")
            .alias("l", "listen")
            .default("listen", process.env.IP || config.host)
            .describe("listen", "IP address of the server")
            .boolean("help")
            .describe("workspacetype")
            .alias("ws", "workspacetype")
            .describe("readonly", "Run in read only mode")
            .alias("ro", "readonly")
            .describe("packed", "Whether to use the packed version.")
            .boolean("packed")
            .default("packed", config.packed)
            .alias("a", "auth")
            .describe("auth", "Basic Auth username:password")
            .default("auth", ":")
            .describe("collab", "Whether to enable collab.")
            .default("collab", config.collab)
            // @lennartcl this should be moved
            .describe("lb.fileserver", "LogicBlox file server Url")
            .default("lb.fileserver", config.logicblox && config.logicblox.fileServerURL);
    }
```

3. At the line `.default("auth", ":")`, type in the username and password you'd like to use in the format of **username**:**password**, e.g. `.default("auth", "user:pass")`
4. You should be all set! Try accessing `11.22.33.44:3000`, and there should be a pop-up prompting for username and password.

On a side note, if you wish to change the profile name (the default "John Doe"):

1. Open the file `/opt/cloud9/build/standalonebuild/settings/standalone.js`.
2. Locate the following code block.

```
user: {
            uid: 1,
            name: "johndoe",
            fullname: "John Doe",
            email: "johndoe@example.org",
            pubkey: null
        },
```

3. Change the the value of `fullname` to the username you want.
4. Reboot BeagleBone Black and go to `11.22.33.44:3000`, and you shall see updated profile name on your Cloud9 IDE.

Comment: WOW !!! That worked like a charm. Just Tested and no words to say how happy I am as I was trying so many things from a week now. Thanks again !!!

Comment: Same here! I think I just got lucky. No problem! :)